# Sequelize: BelongsToMany with Polymorphic Relationships fails on scope after first (successful) try

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

We are running:

- NodeJS v13.11
- Sequelize v5.22.3
- Postgres v11.7-2

I have 3 models, GameVersion, Tag, and TagTaggable (representing the associative entity). A GV can have many Tags, and a Tag can be associated with many GVs (or any other model via TagTaggable).

Models are built with this (not showing the hooks to handle and clean-up after the polymorphism):

**GameVersion**:

```
this.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
    through: {
        model: models.TagTaggable,
        unique: false,
        scope: {
            taggableType: 'game_version',
        },
    },
    as: 'tags',
    foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
    constraints: false,
});

this.hasMany(models.TagTaggable, {
    foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
    scope: {
        taggableType: 'game_version',
    },
});
```

**Tag**:

```
this.belongsToMany(models.GameVersion, {
    through: {
        model: models.TagTaggable,
        unique: false,
        scope: {
            taggableType: 'game_version',
        },
    },
    as: 'gameVersions',
    foreignKey: 'tag_id',
    constraints: false,
});

this.hasMany(models.TagTaggable, {
    scope: {
        taggableType: 'game_version',
    },
});
```

**TagTaggable**:

```
this.belongsTo(models.Tag, {
    as: 'tag',
    foreignKey: 'tag_id',
});

// Polymorphic relationships
this.belongsTo(models.GameVersion, {
    foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
    constraints: false,
    as: 'gameVersion',
});
```

The Tags are applied to a GV by:

```
await gv.setTags(metadata.tags);
```

where `metadata.tags` is a collection of Tag models.

This works perfectly, the first time I run it, and I can see that, debugging into the bowels of the Sequelize `BelongsToMany.updataAssociations` method, the scope is correct on that first time, by looking at `this.through.scope` on the BelongsToMany object.

I get:

```
{taggableType: 'game_version'}
```

Notice the camel-cased key, which is what it should be.

This results in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO "tag_taggable" ("taggable_type","created_at","updated_at","taggable_id","tag_id") VALUES ('game_version','2020-11-27 18:49:34.767 +00:00','2020-11-27 18:49:34.767 +00:00',82,29)
```

The problem arises on any subsequent attempt (meaning it works the first time after starting the server, but any attempts prior to re-starting the server fail), and I can see that `this.through.scope` now results in:

```
{taggable_type: 'game_version'}
```

Notice the snake-cased key.

This results in the following query (notice the lack of the "taggable_type" column):

```
INSERT INTO "tag_taggable" ("created_at","updated_at","taggable_id","tag_id") VALUES ('2020-11-27 18:51:16.423 +00:00','2020-11-27 18:51:16.423 +00:00',83,29)
```

and throws a "not-null constraint violation."

This SEEMS to be down in the guts of Sequelize, but I cannot imagine it not being surfaced already if it were (unless polymorphic m:n is really uncommon).

Has anyone had this experience, and/or can anyone shed any light on what is going on here?

I would really like to use the `setTags` magic method, but I am at the point of just hand-building the TagTaggable objects and stuffing them in the DB myself.

TIA for any insights/assistance,

Chris

Comment: I had the same issue using typescript. All my models have `underscored: true` option but in the scope I was saying `taggable_type: 'user'` and the `taggable_type` field was missing in sql string. As soon as I changed it to `taggableType: 'user'` it fixed the problem.